# Retorno de carro en data studio

Tags: google-data-studio

¿Cómo podría agregar un retorno de carro dentro del concat en data studio. Pues “\n” es ignorado y coloca el campo2 en la misma línea?

(Este es el else de un CASE)
… else concat(campo1,”\n”,campo2)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Aquiles qué agradable que leas y más aún atiendas mi problema. Con gusto detallo un poco más. 
 Necesito crear un campo calculado llamado franquiciados activos. 

Lo he creado del siguiente modo:                                    CASE
WHEN franquiciado2=1 and franquiciado3=0 *THEN* listing member

WHEN franquiciado2=0 and franquiciado3=1 *THEN* selling member

WHEN franquiciado2=1 and franquiciado3=1 and listing=selling=1 *THEN* listing member

Else
Concat(listing member, “\n”,selling member)

End

Comment: El problema que presenta es que el salto de línea es ignorado y la salida cuando entra en el else concatena en una misma celda el nombre de dos franquiciados.

Comment: Bueno, Te invito a editar la pregunta y exponer lo que acabas de mencionar en este comentario usando el tag de codigo, asi todos lo verán mas claro